# Attempting to grab from an API, how do I grab only line "1"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to use the API here:
"https://api.2b2t.dev/prioq"

I need line "1" and line 1 only. I am using snekfetch and nodejs
to run a discord bot to display the number when a command is used in chat.

Looked at a lot of code, questions from here, and reddit posts. Yet, haven't found the right way to only show the second line.

```
snekfetch.get('https://api.2b2t.dev/prioq').then(r => {
let entry = r.body()
```

When I do this the bot only comes up with

```
1566069571000
58
```

I only want the number 58 in this example not the random top number
what would I do?
and sorry for asking for a how-to but I have tried a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is just JSON, so you can access it by index, `entry[1]`.

Side note: [snekfetch is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snekfetch).